# Why Rspec tests with javascript fails on CodeShip?

Tags: rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist, codeship

I'm writing feature tests with: `ruby 2.1.4`, `rails 4.1.12`, `rspec (2.14.1)`, `capybara (2.4.1)` and `poltergeist (1.5.1)`.

Currently I have a feature like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'user is able to import videos from YouTube Channel', js: true do

  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  end

  scenario 'from a simple correct YouTube video link' do
    VCR.use_cassette('video_sources/youtube_add_single_video') do

      visit root_path

      fill_in 'user_email',    with: @user.email
      fill_in 'user_password', with: @user.password
      click_button 'Log in'

      visit youtube_import_path

      expect(page).to have_css("input#query")
      expect(page).to have_css("a#continue-button")

      fill_in "query", with: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZY43QSx3Fk"

      page.find('#continue-button').trigger('click')

      # clicking on '#continue-button' call youtube API
      # receive a video data and store it into DB

      expect(page).to have_content("Congrats! Your import is complete")
    end
  end

end
```

Locally  everything works fine, all tests are green.
But on CodeShip - this scenario always fails.
And I can not find a reason why...

CodeShip log says that:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status
```

But why? Locally all tests are green.

P.S. I tried to add `sleep 5` before line `visit root_path` and it did not help.

P.S.S. Maybe this part of `spec_helper.rb` will be helpful:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `sleep(5)` AFTER `visit root_path` and check again if the test fails

Comment: it does not help :( I have tried to add `puts page.current_url` after `visit root_path` - and it returns me `"page:blank"` instead of `"/sign_in"`

Comment: looks like it does not open the `root_path ` page. but why? O_o

Comment: AND capybara should wait automatically, shouldn't it?

Comment: what's the result of `expect(page).to have_selector('user_email')` ?

Comment: can you try with `visit('www.yoururl.com')` instead of `visit root_path` ?

Comment: the same error. But in other similar tests this problem does not appear. I think it's timeout problem in CodeShip test server..

Comment: There're only one difference between this and other tests - it have `js: true`

Comment: js: true is a HUGE difference --- it means the test is trying to use whatever driver you have set as Capybara.javascript_driver  --- what driver is that? Is that driver supported by codeship?

Comment: My settings is similar to this gist: https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/87bfa2e1f14459eafe7b

Comment: `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist`